# How to handle/ avoid intersect errors when clipping the difference between two layers?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, intersection, topology

Using QGIS + Grass, I've added a shapefile of coastline and islands to my map.

I then buffer this shapefile to create a coastal zone of a known width. At this stage the buffer consists of the offshore (buffered) area + the area occupied by the land/ islands. As I am only interested in the offshore part, I then "clip" the land shapefile from the buffer.

I have tried this using both Vector>Geoprocessing Tools>Difference and GRASS v.overlay.xor. Either approach results in geometry errors (lots of them).

e.g.,

```
segments 0 and 24 of line 43 intersect at xx.xxx, yy.yyyy
```

This appears to be due to narrow connections between land areas (yellow in the picture below) resulting in intersecting nodes after the ocean (blue) is clipped.

[image]

My land data comes from an external source, and I don't have a lot of scope to simplify or adjust this.

What is the best way to handle these errors, or to avoid them in the first place?

I'm not a GIS expert, so there's a good chance that I'm approaching this problem from the wrong end. Would appreciate any tips or advice to avoid these errors.

Comment: If you'd buffer the land polygon layer, you'd only get the off-shore part, right? No further steps necessary. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @underdark. Yes, that's what I was expecting, but in my case the land part is also added. For example, I buffer a circular island, and the resulting shapefile consists of the area of the island + the area of the buffer. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Right, sorry for the confusion, my fault. Did you test validity of the land polygon? I think it might also fail the test. A quick fix should be to move the nodes at the problematic spot apart a little.

Comment: No need to apologies, my explanation of the problem is probably at fault. When I run `Vector>Geometry Tools>Check geometry validity` no errors are detected. Is there a comparable command in GRASS to double check?

Comment: Curious: Which GRASS GIS version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Grass 6.4.2